# position of icons on scaling (flexible) background

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website for a friend of mine.
We got these layout and i've put a flexible background which scales to the current browser size. But the icons placed on the background needs to stay in relative position while scaling the window.
Means if i resize the window it would be fine to have the icons stay on there position.

```
#icon1{

/*Back*/
position: relative;
//margin-top: 20%;
//margin-left:10%;
widht:20%;
top:20%;
z-index:10;
```

}

```
html, body {height: 100%;
      //  width: 1600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow:hidden;
      }

#inhalt {height: 100%;
   //  width: 1500px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     background: url(wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/img/bg_small.jpg);
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     z-index:0;
```

}

[Example](http://torsten.limegreen.it)

At the moment the icons are fixed at their position.

Thank you for your hints

Comment: Here's the way I did it...hope it helps - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha

Answer (score 0):

With the comments from @Paulie_D, I managed to achieve this by, instead of using a backgroud-image for the map, I used an actual image with an img tag. By using an actual image, I the icons scaled to the size of the image (since now the image determines the size of the container). When I used the background image, I had to manually set the height or width of the container, which might not be the actual size of the image.